# How to write gremlin jannusgraph predicate lt, lte, gte etc in java?

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I am developing java backend over  janusgraph database.

**I need to write the below gremlin query in Java**. I know there is a Compare Enum in janusgraph that contains lt, lte ,eq ... but the test function takes two params so I need to know how it is writen in java.

**Gremlin syntax:**

```
 g.V().hasLabel("person").has("age", lte(29))
```

**In Janusgraph I guess !:**

```
  g.V().hasLabel("person").has("age", Compare.lte.test({{XXX}},29))
```

Where {{XXX}} should be replaced by the queried item.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your question as your first query is Java:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").has("age", lte(29))
```

As long as you static import `P.lte` with:

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.P.lte;
```

you can write the traversal that way and it will work just fine. If you don't static import that method then you have to do:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").has("age", P.lte(29))
```

Either way you need to import some aspect of `P`.